# Necessary and sufficient condition so an edge-weighted complete graph has even weight on all cycles

Tags: graph-theory

Let $O\subseteq K_n$ be the subgraph of $K_n$ with odd-weight edges. The problem is to prove that all cycles in $G$ have even weight if and only if $O$ is a spanning complete bipartite subgraph of $K_n$.

I was able to prove one direction. I'll denote by $h(e)$ the weight of edge $e$ and for a graph $F$, $h(F)=\sum_{e\in E(F)}h(e)$. Suppose every cycle has even weight. If $O$ contains an odd cycle $C$ then $C$ would have odd weight, so $C$ contains no odd cycle and hence is bipartite. <strike>To show that it is complete bipartite I showed that there are no non-adjacent edges. Suppose that there are non-adjacent edges, say $uv$ and $xy$ in $E(O)$. Since the graph is complete, $\{ux,uy\}\subset E(K_n)$ so there is a cycle $C=uxy+yu$ with $h(C)=h(ux)+h(xy)+h(yu)\equiv0+1+0\mod 2$, so $C$ has odd weight which contradicts the initial hypothesis.</strike> Finally, suppose that $O$ is not a spanning subgraph. Then there's a vertex $w\in V(K_n)\setminus V(O)$ and we can construct a cycle $uvw+wu$ with odd weight.

But I'm completely stuck on the other direction. I don't even know how to start it. Can someone else me out?

---

**EDIT**

Part of that was incorrect. For the sake of posterity, the correct proof that it is complete bipartite is as follows. We've already shown that $O$ is bipartite. Let $A,B$ be a bipartition of $O$. If $E(O)$ is empty then we are done since all edges have even weight. Otherwise there is at least one edge $uv\in E(O)$; let $u\in A$ and $w\in B$. We may assume that $n\geq 3$ since otherwise there are no cycles to worry about in the first place, so there exists another vertex $w$. WLOG let $w\in A$ and suppose that $vw\notin E(O)$. Then $h(vw)$ and $h(uw)$ are both even so $uvw+wu$ is an odd-weighted cycle.

Comment: It looks like the direction you've already done is the hard one...

Comment: @HenningMakholm that's what I thought at first too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's given that the vertices of the graph can be partitioned into two sets such that the odd-weighted edges form the complete bipartite graph between those two sets.

Now prove by induction on the length of a path in the graph that its total weight is *odd* if it begins and ends in *different* partitions, and *even* if it begins and ends in the *same* partition.

A cycle is a path that begins and ends at the same node, hence in the same side of the partition.

Comment: ...seems obvious now. Dammit...

Answer (score 1):

This is meant to be a comment!

Your proof of the completeness of the bipartite graph is not correct. You assume you have tow vertices in different parts of the bipartition which are not adjacent then construct  an odd weight cycle.

Comment: hmm, I understand what you mean but is there something incorrect about my reasoning above? i.e. is it true that there must not be non-adjacent edges? It seems I've shown something slightly stronger which is that $O$ is a star. But is this incorrect?

Comment: Why are $h(ux)$ and $h(uy)$ both even?

Comment: $O$ is not necessarily a star! Any complete spanning bipartite subgraph will work.

Comment: got it, thank you so much for reading my proof so carefully!